# Не пробрасываются порты извне через роутер к серверу. Почему они фильтруются?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, роутер, порты, vagrant

Роутер (ASUS RT-N10PV2) выходит через белый ip от провайдера. Веб-интерфейс повесил на 8081 порт.
В локальной сети есть linux сервер (через virtualbox+vagrant). 80 порт nginx, 8080 порт apache, 53 порт dns.

В настройках роутерах включил forwarding данных портов.

Но извне всё равно выдает что порт закрыт. а 8081 открыт. До этого веб-интерфейс роутера стоял на 80ом порте и этот порт был тоже открыт.

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-05 02:46 Coordinated Universal Time
Nmap scan report for 161.*.189.89.sta.211.ru (89.189.*.161)
Host is up (0.11s latency).
Not shown: 94 closed ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
23/tcp open telnet
53/tcp filtered domain
80/tcp filtered http
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy
8081/tcp open blackice-icecap

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.29 seconds
```

- вывод nmap.

Пробовал пробросить порт для основного ПК. Всё сработало. Порт открылся.

Фаерволл на серваке отключил. iptables пуст.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.11"
```

- vagrant конфиг подключения.

Т.е.

Adapter 1: nat (forwarding 22 port for ssh), Adapter 2: bridged

Скрины virtualbox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерная схема сети:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Провайдер порты не блочит.

Почему эти порты фильтруются?

Comment: вы открываете порты в vagrantfile?

Comment: Нет.
config.vm.network "forwarded_port" я не юзаю.

как я понял, достаточно config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.11".
+ пробовал с роутера включить dmz на ip сервака. безрезультатно

Comment: Вагрант-машина должна быть переносима, а это автоматом невозможно при жестком задании айпишников. Попробуйте удалить лишний интерфейс и воспользоваться forwarded port, роутер настроить на форвард на windows-машину.

Comment: Не могу согласиться. Есть куча способов сделать виртуальную машину переносимой при жестко заданном айпишнике. К примеру, если виртуалка переносится исключительно в пределах одной локалки - дополнительные телодвижения вообще не нужны.

Comment: я использую и config.vm.network "public_network" просто. это ничего не меняет, потому что я в роутере DHCP присвоил MAC адресу сервера этот айпи.

Comment: Глупый вопрос - а сколько раз в вашем конфиге встречается вызов `config.vm.network` - и нет ли там строчки вроде `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: ...`?

Comment: один и это:
config.vm.network "public_network".

больше нигде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смущает тот факт, что на карте сети у сервера всего 1 адрес - в то время как у сервера аж два адаптера.

Судя по всему, оба адаптера на сервере смотрят в одну и ту же сеть. При этом пакеты идущие через один маскарадятся - а через другой нет. В то же время, маршрут по умолчанию (если настраивать сервер без изысков) может быть лишь один. Если пакет попадет на сервер через один адаптер - а вернется через другой - то он вернется с неверным IP.

В итоге, из двух адаптеров полноценно может работать лишь один.

Изучайте маны по vagrant - текущая конфигурация ненормальная.

Comment: карту набросал сам примерно.
два адаптера это дело рук vagranta.

ifconfig: https://gist.github.com/instantia/364612e0fde968c816f0

Comment: Второй адаптер к сети-то подключен? Попробуйте пропинговать 192.168.1.11 с хоста.

Comment: пингуется всё отлично. и с роутера до сервера и с других устройств до сервера. какая-то магия если честно

Comment: https://gist.github.com/instantia/19ff1b44f57ff34b9df4

Смущает Gateway. разве шлюз не должен быть 192.168.1.1 ?

Comment: Ага, вот в этом и ошибка! Пакеты в одну сторону ходят через второй адаптер - напрямую, а в другую они идут через NAT и у них меняется адрес. Потому-то они и отбрасываются роутером.

Comment: Если задуматься, то получается, что такая конфигурация адаптеров **никогда** не заработает: один из них всегда будет глючить. Конечно, можно настроить iptables так, как это делается в ситуации с двумя провайдерами... Но это точно простое решение?

Comment: Вот я не знаю как мне решить эту проблему. Всё перегуглил про vagrant. Никто не жаловался на это.
Перегонять через windows, а потом к серверу forwarding не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1):

**Проблема решилась**. Спасибо за помощь Pavel Mayorov.
С конфигом vagrantа всё нормально. Видимо в нём это не предусмотрено.

Я просто напросто изменил gateway.

```
sudo route del default gw 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

Создал отдельно скрипт **gateway.sh**.

И вызываю его сразу после включения машины.

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "gateway.sh", run: "always"
```

Более элегантного решения в vagrantе не нашёл.